# Как внедрить live-stream (радиопоток, например), чтобы работало на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: аудио, html5, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача по внедрению звука на вебсайт (html5, jquery), да так, чтобы все работало и на мобильных устройствах! 
Со звуками, загруженными на сайт, проблем нет. А вот с вещанием не получается! 
Пробовал использовать JPlayer, пробовал прямо в хтмл5 внедрить поток - на мобильном не хочет работать, хоть тресни.  
Вот ссылка на поток, который взял с тестовых JPlayer: http://listen.radionomy.com/abc-jazz

Мог бы кто-нибудь помочь, внедрить эту ссылку в хтмл5, так чтобы работало на Андроиде 4 и iOS?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте тег `<audio>` и путь до файла **.m3u**

```
<audio src="http://listen.radionomy.com/abc-jazz.m3u" controls="controls">
Ваш браузер не поддерживает теги <audio> </audio>! Обновите версию браузера!
</audio>
```

Comment: 
Спасибо, но разве вы думаете, что такой способ я не пробовал?? Он работает на ПК, но не на мобильных устройствах. Кроме того, вы пишете: src="music.ogg"  - да, так работает, но music.ogg - это локальный файл, так работает на мобильном. Но попробуйте ссылку на вещание, например так:

<audio src="http://listen.radionomy.com/abc-jazz" controls="controls">
Ваш браузер не поддерживает теги <audio> </audio>! Обновите версию браузера!
</audio>

Comment: вам как нужно. чтобы пользователь зашёл на сайт, нажал на кнопку и у него играла музыка с потока?

Comment: Да, примерно так.  У нас типа "кафе", заходишь и там радио играет. Можешь выбирать поток из списка радиоканалов.